# MediaWiki api JSON parsing error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mediawiki-api

I am accessing the media wiki api using javascript and returning a JSON, but when parsing/accessing the returned data and inserting the datastr variable into an existing div, I receive undefined. Here is my script code:

```
$.getJSON("http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Bulbasaur_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29&prop=images", function(data) {
    var datax = $.parseJSON(data);
    var datastr = datax.images[2];
    console.log(datastr); //prints nothing to the web console
});
```

The link itself is working appropriately I believe, returning a JSON:
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Bulbasaur_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29&prop=images

This may be a problem with either the way I am accessing the API, or just receiving/parsing the JSON.Ultimately, I need the image "001Bulbasaur.png". Thanks!

**Changing datax.images[2] to datax.parse.images[2] returns the same undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var datastr = datax.images[2];
```

To:

```
var datastr = datax.parse.images[2];
```

Update: Seems you are having cross-origin problems, its not making the request. This should work:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Bulbasaur_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29&prop=images",
  success: success
});

function success(datax){
    var datastr = datax.parse.images[2];
    console.log(datastr); //prints 001Bulbasaur.png 
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mRU3M/

Comment: After doing this, I still receive undefined.

Comment: This prints to the console which solves one problem, but it still produces an undefined when I try to insert it into HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/mRU3M/1/. This may be a separate issue than presented by the question though.

Comment: @pran ajax is an Asynchronous process, so you need to put 'document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = datastr;' inside the success function